# Modify translation for value submit button of the joomla login module

Tags: joomla, authentication, module

i want to translate the submit value of the login joomla module

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('JLOGIN') ?>" />
```

Exactly where can i find "JLOGIN" text and thnks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In Joomla 1.6 or above there is a user interface for overriding specific language strings in the language manager. Go to the language manager and select the overrides tab. There are detailed instructions for use in the UI.

Comment: Perfect then. Just use the language override.

Answer (score 0):

These are always defined in your language ini files. A quick search shows: `language/en-GB/en-GB.ini`. The `en-GB` directory will vary depending on your default language.

The current value of this text is `Log in`, for en-GB that is.

Comment: you mean the first line LOGIN="Login"? i need to  modify the frensh translation word (all in capital letter),i modified the fr-FR.mod_login.ini as MOD_LOGIN="CONNEXION" but the button still show "connexion"

Comment: Do not modify the core file, use the language override feature.  MOD_LOGIN is not the key is it? it is JLOGIN.  Keys that are common across extensions are found in the main language file and hence do not have component or module names at the beginning.

Comment: What Elin is referencing is that you should override the file. go to `language/overrides` directory. Create new file called fr-FR.override.ini. In there add a line that has: `JLOGIN=CONNEXION`. If I'm understanding you correctly.